# Cannot edit checkbox (input field in User site guest)

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, inputfield, inputcheckboxes

I have a User site guest which displays fields of an object

For example, if it's a checkbox
If I do

```
<apex: inputField value = "{! loggedC.Expression_rens_F1__c}" />
```

The checkbox appears well but cannot be checked

However, with

```
<apex: inputCheckbox value = "{! loggedC.Expression_rens_F1__c}" />
```

The checkbox can be checked

My VisualForce page is as follows:

```
<apex:page standardController="NewR__c" extensions="VisualisationController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0" cache="false">
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!loggedC.Exactitude_rens_F1__c}" />
</apex:page>
```

My controller is the following:

```
public class VisualisationController {
  Public NewR__c loggedC{ get; set; }
    
  Public VisualisationController(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) {
       try {
            loggedC= [SELECT Id,
                                    Exactitude_rens_F1__c,
                                    FROM NewR__c
                                    LIMIT 1];
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

I also use text fields with inputFields and they also appear uneditable

Currently my VF page is only with apex: inputField (I don't think I'll change it given the large number)

By going to Setup-> Sites-> Click on site -> Public access settings -> Object settings
I see the object is read but I don't see how to put the object in modification
The field is read / Modified
[image]

I'm wondering if I shouldn't create a permission set instead of using the User site guest profile

Do you have an opinion?

Comment: A lot has changed with site guest user permissions in the last year and in general you can only do inserts, not edits.  The only way around is to run controller without sharing.  Here is a [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352282&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) to one article about the changes.

Comment: @gorav Thanks for your response, i run controller without sharing but i still have the same problem : apex:inputField just displays without i can modify but apex:inputCheckbox et apex:inputText allow modifying

Comment: VisualForce Page : `<apex:page controller="VisualisationController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0" cache="false">
<apex:inputField value="{!loggedC.Exactitude_rens_F1__c}" />
</apex:page>`

Comment: Apex Controller : `public without sharing class VisualisationController {
  Public NewR__c loggedC{ get; set; }
    
  Public VisualisationController() {
       try {
            loggedC= [SELECT Id,
                                    Exactitude_rens_F1__c,
                                    FROM NewR__c
                                    LIMIT 1];
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the permission to Edit a field with apex:inputField, we have to put the ignoreEditPermissionForRendering attribute (https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YpKGQA0)

Even if this is resolved, a new error appear
I can't update an object with DML "update" in User Site Guest..
I have the message "core.apexpages.exceptions.ApexPagesGenericException: system.security.NoAccessException: Access in update denied for NewR__c. Controller action methods might not not run
(VisualForce page with customController)

Comment: My second mistake was that I didn't put the ignoreEditPermissionForRendering attribute on all input fields
(to be put to allow the modification of a field of an object when using custom Controller for a guest user site)